# Derivation of rocket equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science, approximations

Let $m$ be the mass of a rocket in free space (including fuel) at the time $t$. Now suppose that the rocket ejects a mass $\Delta m$ during the interval $\Delta t$ with velocity $v_e$ relative to the rocket.

I was told that the correct ansatz is as follows:

$$
mv = (m - \Delta m) \cdot (v + \Delta v) + \Delta m \cdot (v + \Delta v - v_e).
$$

If you work this out, it reduces to:

$$
m \Delta v - \Delta m v_e = 0.
$$

However some books start with the equation

$$
mv = (m - \Delta m) \cdot (v + \Delta v) + \Delta m \cdot (v - v_e)
$$

which reduces to

$$
m \Delta v - \Delta m v_e - \Delta m \Delta v = 0.
$$

Then you need to "neglect" the higher order term $\Delta m \Delta v$ to get the correct result.

Is there any good conceptual reason why the first ansatz is the more correct one?

However if you use $\tilde m = m(t+ \Delta t)$ in the derivation, you get the correct result without the need of neglecting higher order terms in the line of the second derivation:

$$
(\tilde m + \Delta m) \cdot v = \tilde m (v + \Delta v) + \Delta m (v - v_e)
$$

so why is the following equation the conceptually wrong ansatz:

$$
(\tilde m + \Delta m) \cdot v = \tilde m (v + \Delta v) + \Delta m (v + \Delta v - v_e)?
$$

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243598/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197587/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22399/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150780/25301

Comment: Too short to be an answer: Neither one is correct with regard to non-infinitesimal quantities of mass. The reality is somewhere in between. Both are the same with regard to infinitesimal quantities of mass.

Comment: The first method is clearer in terms of _when and when_ you are conserving momentum. Conserve momentum at the snapshot in time $t$: $m(t)v(t)$. Now conserve momentum at the snapshot in time $t + \Delta t$: $m(t+ \Delta t)v(t+\Delta t) + (m(t) - m(t + \Delta t))v_{\text{mass element relative to ground at} t + \Delta t}$.  By velocity addition, we have $v_{\text{element with respect to ground}}(t + \Delta t) = v(t+\Delta t) + v_e(t + \Delta t)$. Notice how since $v_e$ is a variable, I'm leaving it as $v_e$. Why you have a bunch of $-v_e$'s I'm not sure. I don't like how it's taught that way

Comment: As it teaches you to put minus signs everywhere for _what you think_ the direction is, when in reality the math doesn't care and _will always take care of the signs for you_. $v_e$ is as much of a variable as $-v_e$

Comment: You answered your own question. When discussing quantities of 1st order ($v\Delta m$ and $m \Delta v$) you can neglect quantities of 2nd order ($\Delta m \Delta v$).

Comment: +1 for David Hammen. The correct term would be (v-v_e+0.5*/delta v) . The answer is not somewhat in the middle, it is exactly in the middle, because (v+ /delta v) is the average velocity during the time you are considering.